# Jquery Datatables ajax call won't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

I have following dataTables jquery in my js file

```
$("#manage_chauffeurs").dataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "aaSorting": [],
  "ajax":{
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '/admin/reports/chauffeurs_data'
  },
  "responsive": true,
  "aoColumnDefs": [
      { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 14 ] }
   ],
  "columnDefs": [ { targets: '_all', visible: true } ],
  "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
  "aoColumns": [
    { "mDataProp": "name", "sDefaultContent": "", "sClass": "center_align"},
    { "mDataProp": "user_id", "sDefaultContent": "", "sClass": "center_align" }
  ]
});
```

Below is the html

```
  <table class="display responsive no-wrap" id="manage_chauffeurs">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="50%">User Name</th>
        <th width="50%">User ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

  </table>
```

I have the resource `'/admin/reports/chauffeurs_data'` set at my server. However, I don't get an ajax call. No call at all.

Browser console gives the following error:

```
jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:4090 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

Checked for above error, I have no mismatch of columns in my code.
What could be going wrong here?
Someone please help!

Comment: `"dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',` - that looks odd to me as it's labelled `dom` at it clearly isn't valid HTML

Comment: Remove `"aoColumnDefs": [ { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 14 ] } ]` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: i figured out that too. but after posting question